# Page continuously executes when iframe is inserted in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

```
$("#framediv").html("<iframe id='gamewindow' src='http://website.com?frameWidth=" + window.innerWidth + "&frameHeight=" + window.innerHeight + "' height='100%' width='100%'></iframe>");
```

When this line is executed in my page the whole page's content seems to just execute continuously and I'm not sure why. It seems to only do it if I try to insert an `<iframe>` in.

For example if I have the page

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
<script>
$("#framediv").html("<iframe id='gamewindow' src='http://website.com?frameWidth=" + window.innerWidth + "&frameHeight=" + window.innerHeight + "' height='100%' width='100%'></iframe>");
</script>
</html>
```

Hello will be printed on the page continuously.

Comment: Please clarify "just execute continuously". Is it not supposed to execute at all?

Comment: There is no element with that id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the same exact page in the iframe so you keep adding an iframe and that page in the iframe has an iframe and that iframe has a page with an iframe so on until the browser runs out of memory.

Moral of the story, do not include the same page in the iframe.

Comment: The iframe was actually supposed to go to http://website.com/anotherpage but I guess I just forgot to put it in. Stupid mistake, thanks so much!